# How to write() data more than 2G in a time

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I have already defined `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` and  `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` 
 to support open() file that more than 2G. That seems to be all right.

But if I try to write() data more than 2G at a time ( such as 64G ), write() will return a value much smaller than 64G (Exactly 2147479552). I guess that write() only can write data smaller than 2G in a time.

Here is my code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mmap.h>

#define SPACE_SIZE 68719476736

int main()
{
    ssize_t err;
    void* zeros;
    int fd = open64("./test", O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE, 0644);
    assert(fd != -1);
    int zero_fd = open("/dev/zero", O_RDWR);
    assert(zero_fd != -1);

    zeros = mmap(NULL, SPACE_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, zero_fd, 0);
    assert(zeros != (void *)-1);
    err = write(fd, zeros, SPACE_SIZE);
    assert(err == SPACE_SIZE);   // Received SIGABRT, err = 2147479552
    munmap(zeros, SPACE_SIZE);
}
```

How to write() data more than 2G in a time?

Supplementary info:

The result of `readelf -h ./a.out`. a.out is my program's name

```
ELF Header:
Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Class:                             ELF64
Data:                              2's complement, little endian
Version:                           1 (current)
OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
ABI Version:                       0
Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
Version:                           0x1
Entry point address:               0x660
Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
Start of section headers:          6672 (bytes into file)
Flags:                             0x0
Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
Number of program headers:         9
Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
Number of section headers:         29
Section header string table index: 28
```

Comment: Do you actually have (somewhat more than) 68719476736 bytes of RAM?

Comment: 2147479552 is in fact 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 - 4096: exactly one page _less_ than 2GB.  (A gigabyte is 1024 * 1024 * 1024 bytes, not 1000 * 1000 * 1000 bytes.  Do not listen to the hard disk manufacturers' lies.)  Are you using a 32-bit or 64-bit environment?  And I still want to know how much actual RAM you have.

Comment: @zwol  I guess that mmap with options PRIVATE & ANONYMOUS can handle a virtual RAM area exceeding the physical memory limit. Is't that right?

Comment: In fact there are several possible reasons why it might not.

Comment: @zwol I have 8GB RAM and my env is Ubuntu 64bit. You are right, 2147479552 is less than 2GB. My mistake

Comment: What does `readelf -h a.out` (where `a.out` is the name of your test program) print?

Comment: What does it matter?  `write()` is not guaranteed to transfer the whole number of bytes requested in a call in any event, so the only way to safely `write()` more than one byte is to perform `write()`s in a loop, using the return values to keep track of your place and how many bytes remain to be transferred.  Having set that up properly, you should get all the data written via however many calls it takes.

Comment: @zwol  Because of the word limit, I add the result of `readelf` to the question.

Comment: `man write` on my Linux system ends with the following relevant statement: " On  Linux,  write()  (and  similar  system calls) will transfer at most 0x7ffff000 (2,147,479,552) bytes, returning the number of bytes actually transferred."

Comment: Try changing the `mmap` call to `zeros = mmap(NULL, SPACE_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0)`.  If that fixes it, I will explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, and this fact is well documented in `man write`:

> On  Linux,  write()  (and  similar  system calls) will transfer at most 0x7ffff000 (2,147,479,552) bytes, returning the number of bytes actually transferred. (This is true on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems.)

So if you're using Linux, there is no way to write 64GB in a single call to `write()`.

You can, however, create a file which appears to contain 64GB of NUL bytes by seeking to offset 64GB-1 and writing a single NUL byte. (Or, as @o11c points out in a comment, you could use `ftruncate(fd, SPACE_SIZE);`.) Either of those  will create a sparse file which will not actually occupy much disk space, but it will act as though it were 64GB of NULs.

Comment: Digging around in the code I found a constant [`MAX_RW_COUNT`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L2203) which is defined as `INT_MAX & PAGE_MASK`.  So it could be a little different on platforms with a different page size.  (I _think_ all Linux platforms use 32-bit `int`, so that part won't change.)  There is a [comment in the implementation of `readv`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/read_write.c#L765) that makes it sound like the issue is avoiding signed overflow in a possibly 32-bit `ssize_t` return value.

Comment: @zwol: I vaguely remember that comment, but the point stands: there is a limit; it is documented; and RTFM would save everyone a bunch of time. I don't know when reading manpages went out of style but IMHO they continue to be the first stop for information.

Comment: Doesn't `ftruncate` do the same thing as writing a byte after seeking, but without the weird off-by-1 jiggle?

Comment: @rici I have to say that it would never have occurred to me to look at the manpage for this -- because _thought_ I already knew everything the `write` manpage could tell me.

Comment: @zwol: I'm not sure what it says about me that it was my first thought, then :)

Comment: This Q/A is exactly why the Stack Overflow exists - because searching the tubes with Google is faster than finding the information on man pages even after you know what you're looking for

Comment: @rici: Perhaps make [`ftruncate()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html) and [`write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) links to the most up to date man pages, at the Linux man-pages project? Also, `ftruncate()` is superior to writing the one zero at the end, because while both create a sparse file, the latter causes at least one block (of all zeroes) to be written to disk. One can follow that up with [`posix_fallocate()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_fallocate.3.html) to actually reserve storage space for the file data.